# Send data from fragment shader to vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In OpenGL 4.3 can you send data from fragment shader to vertex shader by making an out variable in fragment and in variable in vertex? Is it possible to send from vertex to fragment?
Also how can you send data directly from Application in fragment shader by an instance?

Comment: This appears to be a classic xy-problem.  Why do you want to do this?  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertex to fragment: sure, that's how UV coordinates are usually passed.

Fragment to vertex: no, because the fragment shader runs after the vertex shader. You can, however, fill a buffer, and use that from the vertex shader on the next frame.

Application to any shader: that's just normal input data -- create a buffer object and bind it to the shader program.